# How to change gap between columns in bulma?

Tags: sass, bulma

I would like to know how can i extend default gap between columns in bulma, according [official website](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/gap/) `is-8` gap equals `2em` but i need `6em`,can i override `$column-gap` value in my css file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Sass variable, you can override it but not in a `.css` file, your need to setup Sass [with node-sass](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/) or [with Sass CLI](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-sass-cli/) or [with webpack](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-webpack/), you can also learn more about customisation with sass variables [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/).
All those links point to the official documentation and will help you with the setup. Then you will be able to overrride the value of the `$column-gap` and all other sass variables in a `.scss` file like this :

```
@charset "utf-8";

// Update all the variables you want :
$column-gap: 6em;

// And then import bulma
@import "../path/to/bulma";

// Or import only what you need from Bulma
@import "../path/to/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../path/to/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../path/to/bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@import "../path/to/bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";
@import "../path/to/bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@import "../path/to/bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@import "../path/to/bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";
```